# How to upgrade Android Studio to a version that is not the latest?

Tags: android-studio

I have Chipmunk right now. When I checked updates, AS wanted me to upgrade it to Electric Eel. I chose "ignore" and expected it would give me Dolphin. Now, when I check updates, it says

> No IDE or plugin updates available

Is there a way to update AS to Dolphin from within Android Studio? If not, how can I get the option to upgrade to Electric Eel back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just Open Android Studio and go to setting then search here update.**

for example check this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/onrFX.png

after click on **check for updates** this dialog will show you. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XibFw.png

**if you are ignored these updates** then once click on manage ignored updates.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpkH0.png and remove all and click on **OK**. then click on **Check For Updates..**

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. When I do that, I got "You already have the latest version of Android Studio and plugins installed"

Comment: Okay then once check which version you have currently..?

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I am on Chipmunk.

Comment: Okay now once check this answer i am edited this.

Comment: Thank you. This gets back Electric Eel which I ignored to order to get Dolphin?  Is there a way to upgrade to Dolphin?

Comment: which version you have currently..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251255/discussion-between-romil-mavani-and-hong).

Comment: As I wrote in my question and my comment, I am on Chipmunk.